# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dz}{dt}+e^{t+z}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{dz}{dt}+e^{t+z}=0
$$

I'm having trouble trying to do solve the differential equation above. I have split it like this:

$$
\frac{dz}{dt}+(e^{t})(e^z)=0
$$

But I am unsure how to integrate it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there

$$
\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}t} = -e^t e^z
$$

and from there

$$
{\rm e}^{-z} {\rm d}z = -e^{t}{\rm d}t
$$

Can you take from here?

Comment: oh yea thank you im so stupid

Comment: You're not stupid @QuoraExpert you are just learning.

Comment: @Aryadeva yea but like i just asked  a simple algebra question lol. i feel dumb af for some reason I couldn't see it

Comment: It's separable simply. @QuoraExpert